# Overlay arguments

Tags: 7, organic-groups, modal-dialogs

I'm using Organic Groups and I'm giving users a link to create content for the current group. I do this by giving the path `node/add/grouptype?gids_node[]=1891`.

This works fine, as the group is set by default. However, I can't get this to work on the overlay: `node/1962#overlay=node/add/grouptype?gids_node[]=1961` makes the overlay not appear at all and `node/1961?gids_node[]=1961#overlay=node/add/grouptype` shows the overlay, but I don't think the argument is passed correctly.

Do you have any idea? I can't find any documentation on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out it had nothing to do with overlay and had to do with correctly using [`l()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function. If you want to add a query/arguments to a link using `l` function, you need to give a query argument to it. For example:

`print l("Add page", "node/add/grouptype", array('query' => array('gids_node[]' => $group->etid)));`

Otherwise, the ? will be encoded to %3F